# Pyqtgraph live plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I want to move plot by x-axis, but now all plot points, stay on one screen and start point doesn't move

Window code - main windows code. Function updateplot run every 5s and set new data.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import stack
import pyqtgraph as pgt
from random import uniform, normalvariate
import random

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, stack.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.graphicsView.getAxis('left').setLabel('Data Value', color='#0000ff')
        self.graphicsView.getAxis('bottom').setLabel('time', 's')
        self.graphicsView.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.graphicsView.setYRange(0,10)
        self.graphicsView.addLine(y=5,pen=pgt.mkPen('y'))
        self.graphicsView.addLine(y=7,pen=pgt.mkPen('r'))
        self.curve = self.graphicsView.plot()
        self.L = []
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def getdata(self):
        frequency = 0.5
        noise = random.normalvariate(0., 1.)
        new = 10.*math.sin(time.time()*frequency*2*math.pi) + noise
        return new

    def updateplot(self):
        val = round(uniform(0,10), 2)
        self.L.append(val)
        self.curve.setData(self.L)
        #QtGui.QGuiApplication.processEvents()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Design code generate by designer(stack.py):
Designer with PlotWidget insteadof

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(929, 429)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 901, 321))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Data"))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyqtgraph will show the data of the list, and in your case the list always has the first element so you always see that data. The solution is to use deque with a maximum length, so the last elements will be used.

```
import sys
from collections import deque
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import stack
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, stack.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.graphicsView.getAxis('left').setLabel('Data Value', color='#0000ff')
        self.graphicsView.getAxis('bottom').setLabel('time', 's')
        self.graphicsView.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.graphicsView.setYRange(0,10)
        self.graphicsView.addLine(y=5,pen=pg.mkPen('y'))
        self.graphicsView.addLine(y=7,pen=pg.mkPen('r'))
        self.curve = self.graphicsView.plot()
        self.L = deque([0], maxlen=10)
        self.t = deque([0], maxlen=10)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def updateplot(self):
        val = round(random.uniform(0,10), 2)
        self.L.append(val)
        self.t.append(self.t[-1]+1)
        self.curve.setData(self.t, self.L)
```